# React-native, maps,The prop 'region.latitude' is marked as required in 'MapView' but it's value is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm getting this error when trying to get current location in Expo. I am getting the correct values at console.log though so I don't know what the problem is. In Expo it says 'Exception thrown while executing UI block, NSNull doublevalue: unrecognized selector sent to instance. Here's my code:

```
this.state = { text: 'Destination' ,
  latitude: null,
  longitude: null,
  error: null,

componentDidMount() {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => {
    this.setState({
      latitude: position.coords.latitude,
      longitude: position.coords.longitude,
      error: null,
    });
  },
  (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
  { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
);

{.....}
render()
<MapView style={styles.map}
    region ={{
    latitude:this.state.latitude,
    longitude:this.state.longitude,
    latitudeDelta: 0.1,
    longitudeDelta: 0.1,
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getCurrentPosition()` is async so your initial `latitude` state is null.

Either provide a default non-null value for it or avoid rendering `MapView` until it is no longer null:

```
render() {
  return this.state.latitude !== null && <MapView ... />;
}
```

Comment: how did u do that.. can u please elaborate

Comment: @RishavKumar provide a default non-null value? `this.state = { latitude: <some value>, ... }`

Comment: ya i understand that but I want to give my location. In my component did mount I get my current location through the above function in lat and long and then I pass those values in render.. but then its still showing the same error.. What shall i do if i want to get the current location and show in map'

Comment: Did you initialise your state with some default value when you declare this.state in constructor / class property? Maybe start a new question with your code?

Comment: my code is exactly same as above code.. and default value is null in state

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm saying; give the default an actual value (eg. 1.23) instead of `null`.